# Build a dynamic-dots list to read dataframe one row at a time

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval, httr2

I am trying to build a GET request one row at a time from a dataframe where the possible parameters are a varied and large list, and the dataframe I'm passing to the function may not have the correctly named column headers.

### SAMPLE STARTING DATA

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

dfInput <- structure(list(orig_zip = c("17502", "66616", "M1P2T7"),
                     orig_ctry = c("USA", "MEX", "CAN")),
                row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
> dfInput
  orig_zip orig_ctry
1    17502       USA
2    66616       MEX
3   M1P2T7       CAN
```

### Demonstration Function 1

This first function shows the desired output taken from each row of the dataframe, but here I have it hard-coded and not actually using `...` as I would like.  No flexibility in what parameters are chosen as this is written, but `postalcode = df$orig_zip[i], country = df$orig_ctry[i]` is the sort of code I need inside `req_url_query()`:

```
f1 <- function(df, ...){

  req <- httr2::request("http://some/base/url")

  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    req %>%
      req_url_query(postalcode = df$orig_zip[i], country = df$orig_ctry[i]) %>%
      req_dry_run()
  }
}

> f1(dfInput, postalcode = orig_zip, country = orig_ctry)

GET /base/url?postalcode=17502&country=USA HTTP/1.1
***OUTPUT TRUNCATED***
GET /base/url?postalcode=66616&country=MEX HTTP/1.1
***OUTPUT TRUNCATED***
GET /base/url?postalcode=M1P2T7&country=CAN HTTP/1.1
***OUTPUT TRUNCATED***
```

### Demonstration Function 2

This function makes use of `...`, but I'm passing the actual values in the function call, and obviously this doesn't proceed through the dataframe.

```
f2 <- function(df, ...){
  
  req <- httr2::request("http://some/base/url")
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    req %>%
      req_url_query(...) %>%
      req_dry_run()
  }
}

> f2(dfInput, postalcode = "17502", country = "USA")

GET /base/url?postalcode=17502&country=USA HTTP/1.1
***OUTPUT TRUNCATED***
GET /base/url?postalcode=17502&country=USA HTTP/1.1
***OUTPUT TRUNCATED***
GET /base/url?postalcode=17502&country=USA HTTP/1.1
***OUTPUT TRUNCATED***
```

### Other Efforts

I made several efforts (not all shown) to play around with various `rlang` quoting functions until I got to what you see below, but I feel that this is getting probably too far afield from some more straightforward procedure.

```
f3 <- function(df, ...){
  
  args <- list2(enexprs(...))
  print(args)
  a1 <- lapply(args, \(x) paste0(".data$", x, "[i]"))
  print(a1)
  # req <- httr2::request("http://some/base/url")
  
  # for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  #   req %>%
  #     req_url_query(...) %>%
  #     req_dry_run()
  # }
}

> f3(dfInput, postalcode = orig_zip, country = orig_ctry)
[[1]]
[[1]]$postalcode
orig_zip

[[1]]$country
orig_ctry


[[1]]
[1] ".data$orig_zip[i]"  ".data$orig_ctry[i]"
```

I'm still working on this, but after burning a couple hours, I'm not getting it and could use some help.  I appreciate any that you could offer.  Thank you.

### Objectives (in priority order):

1. Write a package-quality function(s) that will accept a dataframe and an unspecified number of arguments that can generate GET requests one row at a time. I believe `...` is necessary to do this, but am a padawanR, not a JediR, so I'm open-minded on that point.
2. More broadly, I am trying to understand [rlang](https://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html), tidyeval, [data-masking](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html), quosures, quasiquotation, NSE, etc.  I feel some of that is relevant here, but again... padawanR (with an 883 reputation after 9 years ;-) )
3. More specifically to this problem as I laid out in my demonstration functions above, I have an odd situation that feels like it should be a somewhat common problem: I need to get `list(postalcode = "17502", country = "USA")` one row at time from a dataframe with column names `orig_zip` and `orig_ctry`, ***but next time*** I use the function, I might need to pass `list(address = "1 Infinite Loop", city = "Redmond", state = "TN")` from a dataframe with columns `orig_addr`, `orig_city`, and `orig_state`.  So, I have flexible function parameter (`postalcode`) that has to point to dataframe's column name (`orig_zip`) that has to point to one value in that column at a time ("17502").  How do you do that?

Comment: how important is it to use `...`? because I could see your code working with map2

Comment: @Mark, I added some objectives to the question.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use the dots to build an intermediate data frame with `transmute()` that only contains the columns of interest. And then inject rows with `!!!`.

Edit: Instead of `transmute()` you might prefer to use `select()` instead. With the former, you can create new columns with expressions. With the latter, you can use the full syntax of tidyselection to select existing columns.

```r
f <- function(df, ...) {
  req <- httr2::request("http://some/base/url")

  # Transform to tibble to make sure `[` behaves predictably.
  # Also prevents grouped df to disturb behaviour.
  # Use `transmute()` to reduce the data frame to passed inputs.
  df <- df |> as_tibble() |> transmute(...)

  for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
    # Inject row into the query with `!!!`
    req %>%
      req_url_query(!!!df[i, ]) %>%
      req_dry_run()
  }
}

f(dfInput, postalcode = orig_zip, country = orig_ctry)
#> GET /base/url?postalcode=17502&country=USA HTTP/1.1
#> Host: some
#> User-Agent: httr2/0.2.3 r-curl/5.0.1 libcurl/7.85.0
#> Accept: */*
#> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#>
#> GET /base/url?postalcode=66616&country=MEX HTTP/1.1
#> Host: some
#> User-Agent: httr2/0.2.3 r-curl/5.0.1 libcurl/7.85.0
#> Accept: */*
#> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#>
#> GET /base/url?postalcode=M1P2T7&country=CAN HTTP/1.1
#> Host: some
#> User-Agent: httr2/0.2.3 r-curl/5.0.1 libcurl/7.85.0
#> Accept: */*
#> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
```

Comment: I've also simplified the answer after I noticed that httr2 supports dynamic dots out of the box. We don't need `inject()` here.

Comment: That is severely simpler than the direction I was going.  Wow.  The Universe was going to achieve heat death before I stumbled that on my own.